# How do you remap the scroll wheel up and down actions of a Logitech G700 mouse?

Tags: remapping, logitech-mouse, mouse-wheel

I have a Logitech G700 mouse.  I'd like to remap the scroll up and down actions of the scroll wheel to either a key press or macro.  Is this possible using the SetPoint software or some other means?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: Do you still need help, I can remap using Windows Registry

Comment: I can vouch that this is still not supported by LGS. I'd be curious about registry remapping and how dirty that may or may not get

Answer (score 7):

Use [Xmouse Button Control](http://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/XMouseButtonControl.htm) It'll let you re-map any button on any mouse with pretty much any custom action, including running scripts etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. SetPoint will let you change the actions for left and right scroll but I don't see any options in there for up or left scroll, nor even middle click.

There is a guide for what SetPoint can do with your mouse here: http://logitech-en-amr.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/18287/~/customizing-my-g700-with-logitech-software-(setpoint)

Answer (score 0):

You can always try [UberOptions](http://uberoptions.net/) - this should make all buttons  incl. the wheel.

It doesn't directly support Setpoint 6 though, be sure to read the notes on the homepage.

Answer (score 0):

[BetterTouchTool](https://www.boastr.net/) allows you to do so. Go to the normal mouse tab, add a new button, go to the "click here to select mouse button" area and scroll the wheel. It will capture that action and you may assign it to what you want.

Answer (score -3):

Use the new [Logitech Gaming Software](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/support/wireless-gaming-mouse-g700?section=downloads&bit=64&osid=23&selectedFile=http://www.logitech.com/pub/techsupport/gaming/lgs840_x64.exe).

Looks like they are splitting the gaming devices into their own application and device drivers.

Comment: The software doesn't have options for the scroll wheel, only for its buttons.